# Cron not working on one Magento install

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, server-setup, crontab

I'm trying to use the below code which is based on another install which works fine.  I'm at a loss as to why this wouldn't work.

```
/opt/plesk/php/5.5/bin/php -f /var/www/vhosts/gsworkwear.backup.com/gsworkwear.com/cron.php -- -mdefault >> /var/www/vhosts/gsworkwear.backup.com/gsworkwear.com/var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

running with:

```
*/5 * * * *
```

Comment: Check the table cron_schedule in database.Empty table mean not cron jobs set properly.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to put these cron tasks?

To add a cron job to crontab you ssh into the server and run

```
crontab -e
```

You can then add your cron jobs to the cron schedule

```
1 2 3 4 5 /path/to/command arg1 arg2
```

or in your case

```
*/5 * * * * /opt/plesk/php/5.5/bin/php -f
```

Comment: I'm using the Plesk 12 interface.  so domains->gsworkwear.com->scheduled tasks.

Comment: Ah, you'd be best asking on the plesk forums as this isn't a magento question. Unless someone else with experience of plesk comes along and helps. This link may be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700749/setting-up-cron-task-in-plesk-11